# Data not getting aggregated in resultSet for java rxObservable

Tags: java, stored-procedures, rx-java, vert.x

I am trying to call a stored procedure 3 times. When i ran below code, the data from the last call to the stored proc is only displayed inside `resultSet.getRows()`. The data from the previous two calls to the stored proc doesn't appears in the resultSet.Following is my code. Am i doing something wrong. Can anyone help?

```
String currentPeriod = String.format("{call %s.testProc(?)}", params.getJsonObject("databaseInfo").getString("dbName"));
String priorPeriod   = String.format("{call %s.testProc(?)}", params.getJsonObject("databaseInfo").getString("dbName"));
String todayPeriod   = String.format("{call %s.testProc(?)}", params.getJsonObject("databaseInfo").getString("dbName"));
 JsonArray jsonArray = new JsonArray();

        database.dbObject().getConnectionObservable().subscribe(
                connection -> {
                    Observable<ResultSet> resultSetObservable = connection.callWithParamsObservable(currentPeriod, new JsonArray().add(params.getString("testParams")),jsonArray ).                                                                              
                            flatMap(result -> connection.callWithParamsObservable(priorPeriod, new JsonArray().add(params.getString("testParams")), jsonArray ).
                            flatMap(result -> connection.callWithParamsObservable(todayPeriod, new JsonArray().add(params.getString("testParams")),jsonArray );

                    resultSetObservable.subscribe(resultSet -> {
                        handler.handle(ReportUtils.parseSQLResult(resultSet.getRows()));
                    },error -> {
                        error.printStackTrace();
                    },connection::close);

                },err -> {
                    err.printStackTrace();
                }
        );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are trying to do can be achieved by using combineLatest operator which gives results of all your observables (it will wait for all the observables to give result)

Ref http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/combinelatest.html

Pseudo code for this,

```
       String currentPeriod = String.format("{call %s.testProc(?)}", params.getJsonObject("databaseInfo").getString("dbName"));
      String priorPeriod   = String.format("{call %s.testProc(?)}", params.getJsonObject("databaseInfo").getString("dbName"));
      String todayPeriod   = String.format("{call %s.testProc(?)}", params.getJsonObject("databaseInfo").getString("dbName"));
     JsonArray jsonArray = new JsonArray();


    database.dbObject().getConnectionObservable().subscribe(
            connection -> {
                resultSetObservable = Observable.combineLatest(firstCall, secCall, thirdCall)
     firstCall = connection.callWithParamsObservable(currentPeriod, new JsonArray().add(params.getString("testParams")),jsonArray )

      secCall = result -> connection.callWithParamsObservable(priorPeriod, new JsonArray().add(params.getString("testParams")), jsonArray )

     thirdCall = result -> connection.callWithParamsObservable(todayPeriod, new JsonArray().add(params.getString("testParams")),jsonArray )
                resultSetObservable.subscribe(firstRes, secRes, thirdRes -> {
                    handler.handle(ReportUtils.parseSQLResult(resultSet.getRows()));
                },error -> {
                    error.printStackTrace();
                },connection::close);

            },err -> {
                err.printStackTrace();
            }
    );
```

Answer (score 0):

@Bharath Mg. I have modified the pseudo code and it is working for me.

```
String currentPeriod = String.format("{call %s.test(?)}", params.getJsonObject("databaseInfo").getString("dbName"));
String priorPeriod   = String.format("{call %s.test(?)}", params.getJsonObject("databaseInfo").getString("dbName"));
String todayPeriod   = String.format("{call %s.test(?)}", params.getJsonObject("databaseInfo").getString("dbName"));


database.dbObject().getConnectionObservable().subscribe(
        connection -> {

            Observable<ResultSet> firstCall  = connection.queryWithParamsObservable(currentPeriod, new JsonArray().add(params.getString("testParams")));
            Observable<ResultSet> secondCall = connection.queryWithParamsObservable(priorPeriod, new JsonArray().add(params.getString("testParams")));
            Observable<ResultSet> thirdCall  = connection.queryWithParamsObservable(todayPeriod, new JsonArray().add(params.getString("testParams")));

            Observable.zip(firstCall, secondCall, thirdCall, new Func3<ResultSet, ResultSet, ResultSet, List<JsonObject>>() {
                @Override
                public List<JsonObject> call(ResultSet resultSet, ResultSet resultSet2, ResultSet resultSet3) {
                    List<JsonObject> allRecord = new ArrayList<JsonObject>();
                    allRecord.addAll(resultSet.getRows());
                    allRecord.addAll(resultSet2.getRows());
                    allRecord.addAll(resultSet3.getRows());
                    return allRecord;
                }
            }).subscribe(resultSet -> {
                handler.handle(resultSet);
            },error -> {
                error.printStackTrace();
            },connection::close);

        },err -> {
            err.printStackTrace();
        }
);
```

Comment: Cool. By stackoverflow rules, if you've come to your answer from my solution, you should accept mine as an answer :)